# Fluid temperature behavior in vertical and horizontal pipes

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

I have an oil at 350K / 115.3 bar being injected into a vertical pipe from 0m to -200m, flowing into a 500m horizontal pipe.  Ignoring heat transfer through the wall (perfectly insulated), will the fluid heat up in the downward vertical section or cool down?

i.e. which of the curves (red or blue) is correct?

Temperature (K) vs. distance (m):

[image: Temperature vs. distance]

Temperature (K) vs. Pressure (Pa):

[image: Temperature vs. Pressure]